# Deserialize xml returned from rest wcf service on xamarin forms

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I parse xml nodes returned from rest service. I programmed already on xamarin pcl cross-platform, I used many strategies but not one availed here is my working method. I want the string returned to be parsed and bind the node's value to the listview control of xamarin.forms.

ps: xdocument is not working for my case,xmldocument tooenter code 
also ,sorry for over-verbose.

```
public async Task<string> httpRequest(string url)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    string received;

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await 
    Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse,request.EndGetResponse, null)))
    {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
          using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
          {
              received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
async Task<your_type> DeserialseXMLStringFromURL(string url)
{
    var xmlstring = await httpRequest(url);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<your_type>));//initialises the serialiser
    List<your_type> deserializedList;
    deserializedList = (List<your_type>)serializer.Deserialize (xmlstring);
    return deserializedList;
}

// Create a class for your type with properties.

public class your_type
{
    [XmlElement("property_name_in_xml")]
    public string Property_One{ get; set;}

   ....
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks so much , i just delivered the retrieved data as json and used newtonsoft library to deserilaize data in single line                                        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<rootnode>>(jsonString);

Comment: Super, Enjoy :)